# How to display the correct total number of pages count excluding the blank page numbers in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

How we can get correct ‘Page N of M’ and not just raw page count.

Total Page Count property of Crystal Report will need to render all pages of
the report in order to show the count but we need to exclude the blank pages from this

Comment: Why do you have blank pages in your report?

Comment: If you have a fixed number of blank pages, then you can substitute `{PageCount}-{numBlankPages}

Comment: What is causing your blank pages?  If there is specific event/property that causes them, then you could total those up during the `WhileReadingRecords` pass, and then use the formula suggested by PowerUser during the `WhilePrintingRecords` pass.

Answer (score 0):

Page N of M is correct.

You need to figure out why you have blank pages.

Alternatively look into the Section formatting to suppress blank pages. There is a setting for that.

Right click over on the left Section names and choose Format or Format Section.